# Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'PromiseLike<void>'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Im an ionic beginner and was following some tutorials and as I was trying to catch an error I ran into some typescript problems...

> Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'PromiseLike'

Must be an outdated code or something.

Here where the problem is. It happens to every page I try to use the catch.

```
.then(() => { resolve(true);})
.catch((err) => {reject(err);})
```

[image: Here is a screenshot]

[image: Here is another screenshot]

//////////////////UPDATE//////////
Here is the package.json file. Im trying to create a firebase chat app.

```
{
  "name": "chat",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-filechooser": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.1.0",
    "firebase": "^4.7.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.4",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filechooser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepath": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `package.json` file?

Comment: @Sampath updated it

Comment: The problem can be traced easily to the fact that as [you can see here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7bb5fc22c28311b9a08c6188ef6093ee5271c1a3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1291) `PromiseLike` only represents a thennable. I suspect the issue is that you're using an rxjs method that adapts a promise like into an observable, as many do, but since you only posted a screenshot of your coat it's very difficult to say. Please post the actual program text. If your code is simply promises you can adapt the promise by using something like a try catch with async await

Comment: Actually, just use the second argument to then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is probably because the "then" on push returns a ThenableReference which in return causes to return a "PromiseLike". Instead, if you choose to use "set" on push, it will return a then. So the method should read like this

```js
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.firerequest.child(request.recipient).push().set(
        { sender: request.sender }
      ).then(() => {
        resolve({ success: true })
      }).catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
      })
    })

    return promise;
```

Your excerpt from Raja Yogan's chat, so I just pasted code from a different provider. 
Hope it helps.